# How to get Maven to produce two jars for the same project?

Tags: maven

I'm fearing the answer is likely going to be "split the project" but here goes...

I have a project where I need to now output a version of the jar file *without* a log4j.xml configuration. I was thinking it would be nice if I could have dual outputs: one jar with log4j.xml and a duplicate jar without log4j.xml. I'd hate to split the project for just one file. I've tried the Assembly plugin but I don't think I've figured out the correct configuration for that yet.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The best solution in this relationship is **not to use profiles** cause profiles force you to run your build a second time with the activated profile which will not work if you like to use release plugin etc. The simplest solution is to use a classifier like this:

```
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.4</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>second-jar</id>
            <goals>
              <goal>jar</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <classifier>without</classifier>
              <excludes>
                <exclude>**/log4j*</exclude>
              </excludes>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
```

The default bound maven-jar-plugin which is bound to the package phase will create the jar which contains the log4j.xml file and the above will create the jar file without the log4j.xml file which can be accessed by using the classifier **without** or however you name it.

This has the advantage that you simple can create both jar's with a single call of maven like:

```
mvn clean package
```

Also they will be attached to the project and will be deployed to the appropriate repository.

Comment: The release plugin can also be configured with `releaseProfiles` to enable several profiles during deployment.

Comment: This will not work, cause if you have two profiles which are using the same life cycle binding and the same execution only one will win. Apart from that the best way to handle this is that running it without any profiles.

Comment: I'm running this without any profiles and it did exactly what I wanted. I did a diff of the jars and the only change was one of them didn't have the log4j configuration. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can create multiple JARs from a single Maven project. An artifact's classifier can be used to distinguish them.

Maven artifacts are made up of:

- groupId
- artifactId
- version
- classifier

By default the classifier is empty, but you can set it to 'nolog4j' when using the maven-assembly-plugin to exclude the log4j.xml file.

Answer (score 0):

I would use profiles. Create a default profile and a profile without log4j.xml. Invoke mvn package && mvn package -P otherprofile.

Comment: Your answer shows exactly why using profiles is not the best choice. You need to call maven two times.

Answer (score 0):

You can configure the `maven jar plugin` on a second Profile like this:

```
<profiles>
 <profile>
  <id>nolog4j<id>
   <build>
    <plugin>
     <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
     <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
     <version>2.4</version>
     <configuration>
      <excludes>
        <exclude>log4j.xml</exclude>
      </excludes>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
 </build>
</profile>
</profiles>
```

Then you can run `mvn package -P nolog4j` and it should create the same jar but without the `log4j.xml` file ( adjust the `exclude` tag to the actual files path)
More info at [maven jar plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-jar-plugin/usage.html)